# Require ServerName in VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I have the following CNAME record: pear.example.com

Then I have a VirtualHost entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pear.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/pearsite

    <Directory /var/www/pearsite>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't want to show `/var/www/pearsite` to people typing example.com. example.com should show forbidden.

Is there any way to achieve this with Apache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely - you'll want a different virtual host to be the default, and have it serve 403s.

```
# This might already be present in your config, add it if not:
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName catchall
  <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pear.example.com
    # your existing config..
</VirtualHost>
```

Having the 403ing one defined before the real one will cause it to be used as the default for requests that don't match the hostname of a different virtual host.

Comment: It worked! My logs tell me this though: "... httpd[27996]: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release ..."

Comment: @kisplit Oh, then you're on 2.4 - yup, that line is superfluous and can be removed.